# Cast class method appropriately in Kotlin

Tags: swift, kotlin

In `Swift` if you can do the following:

```swift
class MyExampleClass {

   func myMethod(_ value: Int) {

   }

}

let function = MyExampleClass.myMethod // Signature of (MyExampleClass) -> (Int) -> ()
let example = MyExampleClass()
function(example)(10) // Curried
```

How can I achieve the same in Kotlin?

```
class MyExampleClass {

   fun myMethod(value: Int) {

   }

}

val function = MyExampleClass::myMethod // Signature of KFunction2<MyExampleClass, Int, Unit> -- WTF 
val exampleClass = MyExampleClass()
function(exampleClass)(10) // Compiler error
function.invoke(exampleClass, 10) // works but ugly.. 

exampleClass::myMethod as (Int) -> Unit // WORKS!
MyExampleClass::myMethod as (MyExampleClass) -> (Int) -> Unit // UncheckedCast
```

How can I achieve the same functionality as Swift? To be more specific I'd like to be able to pass around a type of `(MyExampleClass) -> (Int) -> Unit` instead of a `KFunction2<MyExampleClass, Int, Unit>`

Comment: Worst case scenario, you can always do `{ obj: MyExampleClass -> { i: Int -> obj.myMethod(i) } }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You can write `function(exampleClass, 10)` instead of `function.invoke`;
2. Kotlin standard library doesn't include currying, but it's easy to implement yourself:

   ```
   fun <A, B, C> ((A, B) -> C).curry() = { x: A -> { y: B -> this(x, y) } }

   val function = MyExampleClass::myMethod.curry()
   function(exampleClass)(10)
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Because the `invoke` method is an operator, you can use the `()` syntax to invoke it.

```
function(exampleClass, 10)
```

Instead of currying as suggested by Alexey, I would use partial application to avoid needless instantiation of the Function2:

```
/** @return partially applied this with the 1st parameter fixed to the specified value */
fun <A, B, C> ((A, B) -> C).invoke(a: A): (B) -> C = { this(a, it) }
```

Called like:

```
function(exampleClass)(10)
```

instead of Alexey's solution:

```
function.curry()(exampleClass)(10)
```

Comment: Could you please be more specific in contrast to Alexey's answer why this is much better? I'm happy to accept this answer if you can show me how its superior. Specifically the `I would use partial application to avoid needless instantiation` if that can be explained in more detail

Comment: In Alexey solution, there are two function instances being created, Function2 and Function1. In my solution, only Function1 is created, because it avoids the step of creating a function to call it. The comparison is more obvious like this:
`function(exampleClass)(10)`    
`function.curry()(exampleClass)(10)`  
You can also notice the amount of code blocks in his curry function is higher. It all fits nicely from all angles.